# Website not loading properlly after clearing vqcache opencart

Tags: caching, opencart, vqmod

i have cleared all my vqcache and now my website does not load properly, 
When i click on a product i get a blank page , the header is messed up,
when i go to check out there is no confirm button, how can i regenerate working vcache?

Any suggestion is much appriciated

Comment: That should happen by itself are you sure you deleted the right files? also what version of OC are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You will have an extension that is causing this or conflicting with another. Look through your vqmod log and system error.log for clues. If still no luck, remove/uninstall all vqmods one by one until you find the culprit and ask extension developer for support.

Also, try deleting mod.cache and checked.cache. These *should* regenerate automatically but sometimes get stuck with code containing errors.